# Как обновить текущую Activity?

Tags: android

Каким образом можно заново вызвать метод onCreate() и обновить, находясь в ней же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы пересоздать активити используется метод [`recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate())

Comment: Типо так можно сделать, чтоб прям наверняка.))))    (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) recreate(); else {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Не думаю, что кто то сейчас разрабатывает под Android 2.x, но если такой желающий найдется, то нужно, конечно, проверять на версию API (такому герою очень часто придется это делать и он, наверняка, сам сможет сориентироваться :)). Остальным такая проверка, конечно, не нужна.

Answer (score 3):

Следующий код заменит текущую Activity без анимации:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```